# My mongodb reactjs redux project, the product list shows in column view (vertical) not row (horizontal). I'm tired

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

// Actions
import { listProducts } from '../redux/actions/productActions';

const Home = () => {

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const getProduct = useSelector((state) => state.getProduct);
const { products, loading, error } = getProduct;

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
}, [dispatch]);

return (
    <div>
        { loading ? <div><Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
              <LinearProgress />
              </Box></div>   : error ? <h2>{ error }</h2> : products.map((product) => (
  

        <div className="row center" key={product._id}>
                <a href={`/product/${product._id}`}>
            <div className="card">
                    <img className="medium" src={ product.imageUrl } alt="product" />
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h2>{ product.name }</h2>
                     <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} />
                    <div className="price">
                         &#8358;{ product.price.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </a>
         </div>
         
  ))}
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Exactly what's the problem?

Comment: On the front page of the application, the product list is in vertical display not horizontal display

Comment: You should share implemented css codes for better helping to you

Comment: I use templates. Before I call for the data from mongodb, It's always in row display but after calling for it, it scattered and display in vertical (column)

Comment: I think dispatch method in the dependency array of useEffect should be removed.

Comment: Yes... Thanks bro. May Allah bless you. It worked

Comment: Thank you so much brother. I've been on this issue for a while. Your suggestion just worked for me. You are appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove dispatch from dependency array of `useEffect` hook